# (android) How to implement multi selection from DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialog

I'm using `DialogFragment` at MainActivity.

Dialog consists of many `TextView` items like picture

[image]

I want to implement multi selection.

If i chooses item, it changed color as a sign of selection in this way.

I have a rough idea of such a method. But I don't know if that's the right way.

Because each item consists of `TextView`. I have to make `variable` and `findViewById` for each item.

I have to implement to `OnClickListner` and change color and return value for each selected item.

Then i think inefficient this way.

Is there a way to process items at once? Or should I do it this way?

Can you tell me a better way?

This is dialogfragment code

DialogFragment.java

```
public class DialogFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment {
    DailyRecordModel drm;
    Button button;
    TextView part;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.check);

        // C H E C K
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: `CheckBox` is suitable for this instead of `TextView`,, You can use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` with this list of `CheckBoxes`s instead of having individual `TextViews`

Comment: It's different from the design I want.
So, Can I use only the `recycler view` and use the `text view` for items?

Comment: yes you can of course .. plz let me know if you want help in this